# Is it possible to split one javascript file to multiple files by swc?

Tags: javascript, swc-compiler

I have a javascript file like this

```js
// file demo.js
export function a(){
// TODO
}
export function b(){
// TODO
}
```

I want to get two files by swc

```js
// a.js
export function a(){
// TODO
}
```

```js
// b.js
export function b(){
// TODO
}
```